Incorrect reading of battery status after wake up (linux only)
My computer is a Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2. OS is OpenSUSE Tumbleweed / Slowroll, dual boot system with Windows 11.
I am having this issue since around February. In Windows everything works fine, but on any recent Linux system I tried (installed Ubuntu and Fedora recently to test it out) I can't get a good reading of my battery charge level after waking up the system from sleep.
This problem occurs whether or not I am using the dedicated GPU driver. Uninstalling / unloading the module / booting a kernel with no Nvidia driver doesn't seem to affect this behaviour.
Below is the BAT0 output of upower -d before and after a sleep/wake cycle:
~ upower -d
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Celxpert
  model:                5B10W13953
  serial:               1713
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 15 Jun 2024 08:45:28 AM EEST (1 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              75.47 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         75.86 Wh
    energy-full-design:  80.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             16.852 V
    charge-cycles:       50
    percentage:          99%
    capacity:            94.3532%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1718430311  99.000  charging
    1718430311  0.000   unknown
  History (rate):
    1718430325  0.000   fully-charged
    1718430311  5.511   charging
    1718430311  0.000   unknown

After waking up, it looks like a parsing error, but I still have no clue regarding the origin of the problem:
~ upower -d
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Celxp:.08'*
  model:                5B10W13953
  serial:               14384
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 15 Jun 2024 08:46:38 AM EEST (19 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              75.45 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         328.96 Wh
    energy-full-design:  80.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         15.332 W
    voltage:             16.63 V
    charge-cycles:       32798
    time to empty:       4.9 hours
    percentage:          43%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-good-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1718430393  43.000  discharging
    1718430388  100.000 discharging
  History (rate):
    1718430398  15.332  discharging

Reading with other tools (e.g. acpi or reading the raw system files) yields the same wrong results, so I ruled out having a upower bug.
Plugging the power in doesn't seem t affect the bad reading either. Once it goes to sleep, it doesn't come back in a sane state.
I suspect it has something to do with the kernel. Version 6.6.26 worked fine for me, sadly it is long gone from my distro's repo and I missed my shot at keeping it installed (due to kernel rotation).
I also had a battery change before all this happening. System worked fine with the new battery (6.6.2x kernels) for a while after installing it, so I'd say it was an unhappy coincidence, but maybe this bit of information helps.
Other lead I have is the power state configuration that might have changed in the kernel. Sadly, I don't know much about S0iX/S3 states, and I would be happy to give up any "modern" benefits in exchange for a working system. Having a random percentage reading after waking up the laptop is my biggest (and only?) issue I ever experienced on a Linux laptop. I was patiently waiting for the issue to get patched, but at this point I think it's a configuration / compatibility issue.
My current system is OpenSUSE Slowroll, freshly installed following a SSD upgrade a few weeks ago. I had some hope a fresh system would also fix my wake up issue, but no luck so far.
Thanks everyone for reading && any help appreciated!
Update: after installing linux 6.6.11-1 from a community repo, everything works again. I'm now slightly switching focus towards identifying a kernel bug in order to report it properly (or identifying a related bug report I can track).

update: apparently all kernels prior to 6.8 are not problematic.
At the moment I'm running kernel 6.7.10 without issues.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
